# Guice Inject Field in class not created by Guice

Tags: java, null, guice, code-injection

I have a class like so, that I create myself somewhere in my code:

```
class StarryEyes {
   @Inject MyValidator validator;

   public StarryEyes(String name) {
      //..
   }

   public doSomething() {
      // validator is NULL
   }
}
```

I want Guice to inject an instance of validator, which has a @Singleton annotation.
I have a module that's loaded at startup and it contains the line:

```
bind(MyValidator.class);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as "validator" is always null. I've tried a number of variations like:

```
bind(MyValidator.class)toInstance(new MyValidator());
```

or other things like that. Is this not how Guice is supposed to work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Typically Guice needs to create objects to inject them. If you just call `new StarryEyes(name)`, Guice isn't ever going to see that object so it won't be able to inject it. One thing you can do is to call `injector.injectMembers(obj)` on the object after you've created it. I wouldn't recommend that, though, as you should avoid referencing the injector in your code.

What you really probably want here is [Assisted Inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject). With Assisted Inject, you'd declare the constructor for your class something like this:

```
@Inject public StarryEyes(MyValidator validator, @Assisted String name)
```

What that means is that `validator` is a parameter that Guice should inject, while `name` must be "assisted" (that is, provided at the time the instance is created).

You then create an interface like this:

```
public interface StarryEyesFactory {
  StarryEyes create(String name);
}
```

With Assisted Inject, Guice can then implement that factory for you. You bind it like this:

```
bind(StarryEyesFactory.class).toProvider(
    FactoryProvider.newFactory(StarryEyesFactory.class, StarryEyes.class));
```

You then inject a `StarryEyesFactory` anywhere you want to create an instance of it. Where you would have called `new StarryEyes(name)` previously, you now call `starryEyesFactory.create(name)` instead. When you call `create(name)` on the factory, it will take the name and pass it to the constructor and provide the bound validator itself.

**Starting in Guice 3**, you do this using a [FactoryModuleBuilder](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html):

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(StarryEyesFactory.class));
```